# os walk with specific extension

Tags: python, pathlib

I want to loop through files with extension ends with CR2, CR3, cr2, cr3 (contain cr in the extensions) only. Currently, I am using os.walk() but people recommend to use pathlib which I can do something like `path.glob('*.jpg')` but still I cannot specify the desired condition. Is there a better way to do this?

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(cfg.RAWIMG_DIR):
    dirs.sort()
    for file in files:
        if dir > '10':
            path = Path(root) / file
            if 'cr' in path.suffix.lower():
```

---

Additionally, since there are too many files, I would to process portion by portion (Say 10 files at a time) during the loop. This is why I need the list of dir names as well.

Comment: `list(Path('top level path').rglob('*.cr*'))` will be easiest, and gets all the cases.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. but does it include *.CR* cases?

Comment: As per my first comment **and gets all the cases.**, why don't you just run it and see. I don't have any CR / cr extensions, so I tested it with `'*.jp*'`, which returned all `.JPG` and `.jpg` files.

Comment: The requirement to process batches of 10 seems suspicious; surely it's better to process one by one as you encounter them? But a simple implementation is to push the matches to a list and the process it and empty it when it reaches 10 elements, or you fall off the end of the loop.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `'*.cr*'` matches `random.crap` too. You can tighten it up to `'*.[Cc][Rr][23]'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) you could do this:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(cfg.RAWIMG_DIR)
for file in path.glob("**/*.[Cc][Rr][23]"):
    print(file)
```

the `**` part of the glob will match all the subdirs of `path`.

Note that this glob also matches `*.cR3` and `*.Cr2` etc (mixed-case). not sure if you want that.

---

if you want to match the suffixes exactly you could to this:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(cfg.RAWIMG_DIR)
suffixes = {".cr2", ".cr3", ".CR2", ".CR3"}
for file in path.glob("**/*.*"):
    if file.suffix in suffixes:
        print(file)
```

---

note that both versions print the full path of the files.

and both versions are lazy. you could turn any one of them into a generator and use `batched` (from the [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=islice#itertools-recipes)) in order to get batches of files to work on.

Answer (score 1):

I hope, this work for your solution.

```
import os
# os.listdir list the files in a directory
for file in os.listdir('./cr_folder'):
    # checks cr 
    if file.split('.')[1].lower()[:-1] == 'cr':
        print(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using glob with the pattern from the extensions you need?

```
from glob import glob
files = glob("*.[Cc][Rr]*")
print(files)
```